# How to generate a lot of session IDs in PHP?

Tags: php, c, security

I am troubleshooting a recent session ID collision and want for this purpose exercise the function [php_session_create](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/34792280bcd2210784ba574d52fc3619cc06160d/ext/session/session.c#L279) and compute an empirical probability for this function to generate colliding session IDs in some standardised (labor) conditions.

However that function is not directly bound in PHP, but seems to be only indirectly accessible.  What would be the easiest strategy to generate a lot of session IDs?

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: @Pepo_rasta I reworded the question and hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate random strings you can use PHP's [mcrypt_create_iv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) function.

```
$NUM_BITS = 256;
$random_bits = mcrypt_create_iv($NUM_BITS / 8);
$printable_key = base64_encode($random_bits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Burp Suite's sequencer](https://portswigger.net/burp/sequencer.html) to make multiple cookieless requests to your site, and capture the session ID generated for each one.

Burp can then analyze the captured sessions IDs to display estimated entropy.